# Invoking the admin service wso2 Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use wso2 (server version 5.9) admin api and got [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-authenticate()). Based on the document I made changes in

```
<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml file
```

restarted the identity server.

invoked url `https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl`

but it shows `Error 403 - Forbidden`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 5.9.0, we can't change the carbon.xml. The corresponding configurations will be templated and managed in single file in /repository/conf/deployment.toml

For this use case, you need to

```
[admin_service.wsdl] 
enable= true
```

Refer this new 5.9.0 doc : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/calling-admin-services/